# How to delete data when navigator from screen to another in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dart-null-safety

every one!
My problem is when I store the data in the list coming from the api and I display it on one page and then go back to another page and when I go back to the old page, the data is still there. Why ???
How do I delete the data??

Comment: Please include sources for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

In the code block that contains navigating logic, you can assign empty data to the data stored variable.

```dart
onTap: () {
  variableContainingData = ''; // assign empty data here

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()),
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear list initially then you need to implement that functionality in onInit() method.

Bellow code would be helpful for you.

```
      List yourList = [];

      @override
      void initState() {
        yourList.clear();
        super.initState();
      }
```

and at the time of navigation you can also clear your list based on your requirement:

```
onPressed: () { 
    yourList.clear();
    Navigator.push(  
      context,  
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),  
);
```

}

But if you want to add some product at the time of page initialization then you need to add that specific logic(based on requirement) also in initState() method.

Comment: I think you mean 'initState' method not 'onInit'

Comment: Actually, onInit() is similar to initState() in GetX. i have correct code. please check again.